# Why does CSS looks different

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML retrieved from a database so I have no control over it and it looks different than if I just put it inside a div :

[image: here is the html retrieved from database]

[image: and here is the one fron inside the div]

And here is my CSS:

```
#cvDiv {
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left: 300px;
    border: none;
    width: 720px;
    display:inline;
    background-color:White;
    text-align:justify;
    padding:15px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #888;
    z-index:auto;     
}
```

and here is the HTML:
           http://jsfiddle.net/ug96v/

What am I doing wrong?

And what I want to do is a make the the top picture look like the bottom one.

**EDIT**

This ended up being a DOCTYPE problem.

Comment: Hard to say if you didn't write what you want achieve.

Comment: sorry about that. added to the main post

Comment: Also, posting 'retrieved from database' code would help, as we have no idea what your database (or web server) do with it.

Comment: there is alot of code in the database so i can't post it but both the codes are exactly the same

Comment: @Wahtever If pages are exactly the same, then they should look the same.  Otherwise, it's hard to find what causes two pages to look different if we have no access to either.

Comment: The server side code has little impact on the CSS, except for the mark-up it produces. Post the rendered html ('view source' in the browser), and we'll try and make sense of that. Though we may ask for more input/details as appropriate, in order to better-help you.

Comment: i didn't mean that i can't share , what i meant was it was to big to share here so i added it to jsfiddle and added the link to the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `position:absolute;`, it forces the div to position itself relative to the the first parent container that has `position:relative;`. It may be causing part of the problem.

Comment: it's still the same after changing the position

Comment: We need to have access to both pages so we can see the full picture. Alternatively, open the pages in Firefox and use the Firebug plugin - it allows you to adjust the CSS while still on the page.

Comment: i already tried firbug but there is two many elements to change manually specially that this is only one of many pages